# Java regex comparing group to string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to do a replacement using regex. The relevant piece of code is as follows:

```
String msg ="    <ClientVerificationResult>\n " +
            "      <VerificationIDCheck>Y</VerificationIDCheck>\n" +
            "    </ClientVerificationResult>\n";

String regex = "(<VerificationIDCheck>)([Y|N])(</VerificationIDCheck>)";
String replacedMsg= msg.replaceAll(regex, "$2".matches("Y") ? "$1YES$3" : "$1NO$3") ;
System.out.println(replacedMsg);
```

The output of this is

```
<ClientVerificationResult>
   <VerificationIDCheck>NO</VerificationIDCheck>
</ClientVerificationResult>
```

When it should be

```
<ClientVerificationResult>
   <VerificationIDCheck>YES</VerificationIDCheck>
</ClientVerificationResult>
```

I guess the problem is that `"$2".matches("Y")` is returning false. I have tried doing `"$2".equals("Y");` and weird combinations inside `matches()` like `"[Y]"` or `"([Y])"`, but still nothing.

If I print `"$2"` the output is `Y`. Any hints on what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use Java code as the replacement argument for `replaceAll` which is supposed to be a string only. Better use `Pattern` and `Matcher` APIs and evaluate `matcher.group(2)` for your replacement logic.

**Suggested Code:**

```
String msg ="    <ClientVerificationResult>\n " +
        "      <VerificationIDCheck>Y</VerificationIDCheck>\n" +
        "    </ClientVerificationResult>\n";

String regex = "(<VerificationIDCheck>)([YN])(</VerificationIDCheck>)";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);

Matcher m = p.matcher( msg );
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
while (m.find()) {
    String repl = m.group(2).matches("Y") ? "YES" : "NO";
    m.appendReplacement(sb, m.group(1) + repl + m.group(3));
}
m.appendTail(sb);
System.out.println(sb); // replaced string
```

Comment: I thought I could get away with not using `Matcher` and `Pattern`. I guess I was wrong.

Comment: I guess you could, but it would require parsing it twice.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking the literal string "$2" to see if it matches "Y". This will never happen.

Comment: Afaik, `"$2"` here evaluates to the second group, which in this case is `Y`.

Comment: No, you haven't actually evaluated the string "$2" in the context of your regexp. It is the literal string "$2" that you are calling `matches()` on. It is a string literal, which means it cannot be anything but "$2". You want to evaluate it first (see anubhava's answer for clues here).

Comment: If I do `msg.replaceAll(regex, "$2".matches("Y") ? "$2" : "$2");`, `System.out.println(replacedMsg);` will print `<ClientVerificationResult>Y</ClientVerificationResult>`. Why does it get evaluated in one and not in the other?

Comment: Because your ternary expression (`"$2".matches("Y") ? "$2" : "$2"`) returns "$2" - the last "$2" I should note, not the one in the middle - which is **then** evaluated by the call to `replaceAll()`. Before `replaceAll()` does its thing you are dealing with the literal string "$2" in all three places above. Java chains its calls and works from the inside out. First it says "does `$2` match `Y`? No, so I will return `$2`." Then it invokes `replaceAll()` which turns this `$2` into the actual match.

Comment: Yeah, even inside `replaceAll(...)` call, it is still just a plain `"$2"` string that never matches regexp `"Y"`. Thus the condition of ternary expression always returns false.